# R adding to a difftime vector forgets about the units

Tags: r, datetime, vector, seconds, minute

When I extend a vector of difftimes by another difftime object, then it seems that the unit of the added item is ignored and overridden without conversion:

```
> t = Sys.time()
> d = difftime(c((t+1), (t+61)), t)
> d
Time differences in secs
[1]  1 61

> difftime(t+61, t)
Time difference of 1.016667 mins

> d[3] = difftime(t+61, t)
> d
Time differences in secs
[1]  1.000000 61.000000  1.016667
> as.numeric(d)
[1]  1.000000 61.000000  1.016667
```

This is in R 3.1.0. Is there a reasonable explanation for this behavior? I just wanted to store some time differences in this way for later use and didn't expect this at all. I didn't find this documented anywhere..

Okay, for now I'm just helping myself with always specifying the unit:

```
> d[3] = difftime(t+61, t, unit="secs")
> d
Time differences in secs
[1]  1 61 61
```

Comment: This behavior by R is super bad!  I suddenly feel much worse about life, after this bit me.

Comment: I also think this deserves a fix or at least a warning in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `help("difftime")`

> If units = "auto", a suitable set of units is chosen, the largest possible (excluding "weeks") in which all the absolute differences are greater than one.

`units = "auto"` is the default.  So for a difference of 1 and 61 seconds, if you were to choose minutes,

```
difftime(c((t+1), (t+61)), t, units = "min")
# Time differences in mins
# [1] 0.01666667 1.01666667
```

One of those is less than one, so by default since you did not specify the units R chose them for you according to the guidelines above. Additionally, the units are saved with the object

```
d <- difftime(c((t+1), (t+61)), t)
units(d)
# [1] "secs"
```

But you can change the units with `units<-`

```
d[3] <- difftime(t+61, t)
d
# Time differences in mins
# [1] 0.01666667 1.01666667 1.01666667
units(d) <- "secs"
d
# Time differences in secs
# [1]  1 61 61
```

Comment: Okay thanks, that makes sense. So the units are just an attribute to the vector that is not checked when I assign a new value. I guess I was expecting this assignment to be smarter - after all there is quite some type conversion when I add a string to a numeric vector.

Comment: You can change the units with `units(d) <- "mins"` and it gets recalculated